# Random greyed out window appears and doesn't seem attached to any app

Tags: window-manager, bug, malware

This random grey, translucent window keeps appearing on my screen. I can click and drag it around (it usually sits on the bottom of my window) but it sits on top of all windows and I can't seem to find what it's attached to. It doesn't show up on mission control and I'm worried I have some sort of virus or spyware. What is this window?

[image: Random grayed out window]

Following the answer from @pion I got the following. Any idea what NSApplication is?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq2hT.jpg

Comment: Does this persist after restart?

Comment: Have a look at ActivityMonitor. Do you see any process that might cause this?

Comment: It does persist after restart! and I have a lot of processes that I don't understand, so maybe. What would I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to determine ownership of any graphical element is by using **[Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/257/)** from the `Xcode` developer tools.

1. [Install **Xcode**](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)
2. Navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app` and right-click to use the *Show Package Contents* contextual menu option so that you can look inside the `Xcode` app bundle.
3. Open `Accessibility Inspector` from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility Inspector.app`
4. Make the `Accessibility Inspector` window large enough to see the *Hierarchy* section.
5. Click the crosshair button near the top right of the window to enable the "Point To Inspect" feature.
6. Click on your mystery gray window so that it gets highlighted in green.
7. The process which owns the window will be listed in the *Hierarchy* section. If this process isn't immediately familiar to you, feel free to take a screenshot and post it here.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this answer, I added the screenshot of the hierarchy! (sorry for the link, stack was giving me trouble)

Comment: @Travasaurus Cool. Looking at your screenshot, apparently there is an app or process literally named `Rectangle` running on your machine. Now the question becomes: Where does that process live, what (else) does it do, and how did it get there? Let's start with an easy first pass at this: Can you amend your original question by adding a code block containing the result of the command `ps auwwx`? (Please make sure to inspect the output first for any possibly sensitive information before posting here.) I'd recommend doing this right after reboot, so that the process list is as short as possible.

Comment: Solved! It was the application [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com). It persisted after restart because the app turns on with the computer! I quit Rectangle and it vanished!

Comment: I also didn't see it before because it doesn't appear on my application bar! so I forgot it was still running when I "quit all apps"