# What’s that coloured icon with an A inside it in text?

Tags: macos, icon, text, sonoma

I have just upgraded my Mac to macOS 14 Sonoma, and noticed a little icon appearing in text if I wait long enough.

The icon looks like this:

[image]

with the colour depending on the application.

It only appears after a while (about 10 minutes), and disappears when the text loses focus.

This is what it looks like in Notepad:

[image]

I’ve also noticed a caps lock icon, but that’s pretty clear.

So, what is it?

Comment: What do you mean with „appearing in text“, can you provide a screenshot showing more context?

Comment: @nohillside I’ve attached a screen shot, though I missed the insertion point.

Comment: So you enter text, leave the window (and the Mac) alone for 10 minutes, and then the icon appears?

Comment: @nohillside That’s right. 10 minutes is a long time to wait for it to happen, so I don’t know what it’s trying to tell me. It happens in other text based windows as well.

Comment: See my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448923/random-greyed-out-window-appears-and-doesnt-seem-attached-to-any-app/448954#448954 . I suggest following the same procedure to see what process is responsible for that image.

Comment: Do you have multiple keyboard layouts setup? Seen an anecdotal comment re 'A' [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/caps-lock-icon.2391867/post-32574467), and an Apple [features document](https://www.apple.com/macos/sonoma/pdf/macOS_All_New_Features.PDF) makes reference to an icon appearing when keyboard layouts are changed. However, this doesn't explain it happening after a long delay.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the new keyboard layout indicator.  A would normally stand for English.  Whether there are settings under Accessibility or cursor that can change how this looks or works I don't know yet.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Ah, the keyboard layout. Yes, I have two layouts (the other is Japanese), and the icon appears immediately when I switch layouts. I can’t see why it needs to remind me after 10 minutes, though.

Comment: This may have been solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248249/disable-macos-sonoma-text-insertion-point-cursor-caps-lock-indicator/77256214#77256214

Answer (score 3):

It's the new layout and caps-lock indicator.

You can disable it with:

```sh
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/FeatureFlags/Domain/UIKit.plist redesigned_text_cursor -dict-add Enabled -bool NO
```

(or re-enable it with `YES`)