# Language bubble randomly popping up, sometimes without any user interaction

Tags: macos, language

The language selection bubble (see image below) has randomly been popping up when I have text fields selected. And it remains until I select something that is not a text field or switch languages. I'm wondering how I might be able to make it stop.

The language swap bubble I'm referring to looks like this:

[image]

It normally pops up only when clicking the language selection key. In which case, it pops up showing what language it is switching to like this:

[image]

However, for the last several months, the bubble has been popping up randomly a couple times a day, with my current language highlighted as in the first image. If I move the cursor within the same text field or another text field, the bubble remains popped up. I can make it go away by either deselecting a text field or by changing languages.

Interestingly, this occurs without any interaction from me. I'll often have stepped away from my computer and have it be popped up when I come back. Or when I pause in typing, it will pop up while I'm thinking for a moment. However, I should note, that it does not *only* pop up while there's no interaction. It also appears while I am in the middle of typing.

Also notably, the equivalent larger language change pop up that appears if you switch languages when a text field is not selected, does not randomly pop up. It's only the version that appears when you switch languages while a text field is selected.

If anyone has suggestions as to why this might be happening, and how I can make it stop, that would be useful. It's not a major issue, but it's a bit annoying.

macOS: 14.2.1

Comment: Is this relevant ?    https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007827

Comment: Hi @TomGewecke, thanks for one possible workaround. This makes is so that the new type of text field language change bubble never pops up in anyway. It appears this will work to some degree. I would actually prefer to keep the new style language change bubble over the old style popup. So it's not a perfect solution, as it forces the old style popup. However, if it's the only way to get the bubble to stop popping up when it's not supposed to, then it's still better than nothing. Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464783/what-s-that-coloured-icon-with-an-a-inside-it-in-text/465466#465466

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248249/disable-macos-sonoma-text-insertion-point-cursor-caps-lock-indicator/77256214#77256214